# How can I force a cached css file to be reloaded on a JSP (i.e. not PHP)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, caching

I am altering a css file which will make drastic changes to my site. Is there a way to force the clients to reload the css so that they pick up the new changes. Unfortunately asking thousands of people to CTRL + F5 or clear their cache isn't an option. I read on a couple of blogs about appending todays date on the css filename as a parameter would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a unique query string parameter on to the end of the css file url

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/my/css/file.css?123" />
```

Just increment the number each time you make an update.

EDIT:

To load it from the web.xml file use the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/my/css/file.css?<%=application.getInitParamer("cssBuildNumber")%>" />
```

and this in web.xml

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>cssBuildNumber</param-name>
   <param-value>123</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I was looking for a more automated solution. But that will work for now. Do I need to change anything in the css file to reference that 123 addition? Or does the browser just reload it automatically?

Comment: You could add a value generated in your jsp such as the current system time. file.css?<%=System.currentTimeMillis()%> but this would cause the file to never be cached which would be bad. Ideally you only want to clear peoples cache when you make an update.

Comment: No the browser will see it as a unique URL that it has never visited before so will download it again. You could if you wanted store the number as a context parameter in your web.xml file and load it from there rather than just typing it straight into the jsp file. Then it would could be used globally for all css files.