# css that starts with selector ^= dont work after changing class with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

When loading page into browser everything looks fine and the background-image is correct. But when I click on the icon and the javascript changes the class of the icon to .icon-myapp-cow the css from [class^="icon-myapp"] is ignored. Only the css from icon-myapp-cow is applied. Tested in chrome and IE9

My css

```
[class^="icon-myapp"] {
    background-image: url("../img/myapp-icons.png");
}

.icon-myapp-horse {
    background-position: -1px -1px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}

.icon-myapp-cow {
    background-position: -51px -1px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

My html

```
<i class="icon-myapp-horse icon-clickable"></i>
```

My javascript

```
$(".icon-clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("icon-myapp-horse");
    $(this).addClass("icon-myapp-cow");

});
```

Comment: Look this Stackoverflow Thread, i think it work for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647618/how-can-i-force-a-cached-css-file-to-be-reloaded-on-a-jsp-i-e-not-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `^` to `*`

When you remove the class `icon-myapp-horse` and then add `icon-myapp-cow` this newly added class is appended to the class names so the new set of classes look like `icon-clickable icon-myapp-cow` hence it does not start with `icon-myapp`

http://jsfiddle.net/Pj3d5/1/

Comment: Aha. That explains a whole lot. Would it be possible to check for a class starting with a text, regardless of what position the class has?

Comment: My workaround resulted in this: '[class^="icon-myapp"], [class*=" icon-myapp"]'. Now the selector will select all elements containing a class starting with "icon-myapp"

Comment: @user2630328 This is not actually doing what you expect it to do. The work around you have posted is as good as just using `[class*=icon-myapp]` the other class `[class^=icon-myapp]` is just not required.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `[class^="icon-myapp"]` to:

`[class*="icon-myapp"]`

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for some more information, and here for a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/te95U/)

> **[attr^=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is the (sic) *prefixed* by "value".
>
> **[attr*=value]** Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value *contains* at least one occurrence of string "value" as
>   substring.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. You are right, this will work. Only thing is that I use prefix on purpose to prevent the css to be applied to classes like "test-icon-myapp-image" or simular.